# fluid columns with 100% height image

Tags: css, height, fluid-layout, dynamic-columns

I'm trying to set up a fluid column layout for a site I'm working on. I'd like to do this without javascript, but it's looking like that might end up being the easiest option. Regardless, anyone know how to get this done with CSS?

Both columns need to fill the browser height. The left column contains an image with an aspect ratio of 2:3, with height: 100% and width: auto, so the left column's width will change depending on how tall the browser is. The right column needs to fill the remaining space.

I saw a trick using float:left and overflow: hidden that's working great, except the divs do not resize themselves correctly when the browser window is resized.

Here's a simplified fiddle to demonstrate the problem, with the CSS below:

```
.left-column {
    float: left;
}
.left-column img {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
}
.right-column {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.left-column, .right-column {
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v7unnhnc/2/

It seems like .left-column doesn't resize itself automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

basically your code works ok. You may add `display:inline-block` to your left column and you will see the img container adapt when resizing vertically, however the text won't flow properly this time.

The problem (if a problem) is that the width of your container (left one).. the one with  your `width:auto` (and you don't really need to add it to your css as your image will set the width of the container when overflow is hidden.. when floating) won't understand the resize of the img without reloading the page even if you visually can see it.

But it's important to know as many web developers these days are too much focused into (imho) making a responsive design while resizing the window that GOAL is not that. The main goal is your web to adapt to whatever window size your users (or future users) have at the moment they load your web. And your code is right on that.

Just people like us may go into a web and start resizing manually the window to check the responsiveness.. and even then, the vast mayoritie of us with just check it resizing on the x-axis.

The chances you have to get someone notice your web not working ok when resizing the window (y-axis) is... well, I hope you have SOO many pepople noticing. that will mean you have a lot of visitors.